# How long should a personal statement be for a UK New Route PhD programme?

Tags: application, application-cover-letter

I'm applying for a few New Route PhD programmes in the UK. The way they are different from traditional PhD's is that they are preceded with one year of Masters in Research which gives you a good foundation in your subject, before you choose your exact research subject.

I was wondering what is the expected application personal statement length for such programmes. I don't want to flood the application commission with words but I also don't want to seem like I haven't put effort. Currently I'm aiming for 4000 characters, which is the same as the upper limit for UK's undergrad applications. On the other hand, undergrad applications aren't supposed to contain academic CV so I might make it shorter to avoid repeating information.

Most of what I could find online about personal statement length related to either US Application Essays (much longer), UK Research Proposals (very specific) or UK undergrad personal statements (simpler). I was wondering what others think about this particular case.

Comment: I don't know if there's a definitive answer to this. It is definitely worth seeing if there is any specific advice given by the universities or departments you are applying to (check their websites). If it helps, my personal statement for my PhD applications was a single page (I felt, as a scientist, I should be concise).

Comment: I checked the websites and they carry no information about this. Some of them have a vague list of things which such PS should contain, but no guidelines about conciseness / the floweriness of the language.